# Got Error "! Missing $ inserted." when using \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I use the following code to include a rotated figure but failed because of this error. I found the problem is with `\includegraphics` but I cannot see what went wrong.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document} 

\graphicspath{ {D:\Update} } 
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics{figure1.png}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable. `\Update` is not defined here, and is probably the source of the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Jubobs: I don't think the OP intended `\Update` to be a macro here, but meant directory 'Update' on drive 'D:\`.

Comment: @user41485: I do not get the same error when compiling the given code but the error `! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ->D:\Update`, because the `\Update` is taken as a macro which isn't defined. Please ensure that this example document really produces that exact error.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Sorry, I had overlooked your comment. You must be right.

Comment: please change \Update to /Update

Answer (score 5):

This is because `\Update` is interpreted as a macro here.
In LaTeX documents you need to use `/` instead of `\` in file paths. Also a trailing `/` is required because later the file name is simply placed directly after the path.

Therefore you should use `\graphicspath` like this: `\graphicspath{{D:/Update/}}`

Comment: If `\Update` really is a macro containing a path, does it contain underscores `_`?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Underscores in file paths are OK. The path should not be typeset internally here, so I don't get how this error message is thrown. Maybe this isn't a correct MWE.